# Method for checking if string is getting empty text or numbers isn't working

Tags: java, android

I'm using this check in android with new floating labels for edit text and method works like this. If string gets empty text or numbers, i'm setting an error message to edit text. It works if i only check if string is empty, but when i try to check if string is getting some numbers, it isn't working. Here is my code:

```
private boolean validateLastName() {
    String checkLastName = inputLastName.getText().toString();
    if (checkLastName.trim().isEmpty())
        for (int i = 0; i < checkLastName.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(checkLastName.charAt(i))) {
                inputLayoutLastName.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_last_name));
                requestFocus(inputLastName);
                return false;
            } else {
                inputLayoutLastName.setErrorEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    return true;
}
```

and this is how i'm using it:

```
if (!validateLastName()) {
        return;
    }
```

**Edit:**

For Example this is working fine, but above code does nothing and below code is showing an error(I mean an error message for user):

```
private boolean validateName() {
    if (inputName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        inputLayoutName.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_name));
        requestFocus(inputName);
        return false;
    } else {
        inputLayoutName.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Add an example where this code goes wrong. Add the expected and the actual output!

Comment: Why are you performing a detailed check it if it *is* empty after trimming rather than if it's *not* empty?

Comment: First of all, I think you should add a '!' in your if condition.

Comment: @anna didn't solve the problem. I don't know why the method with checking if string is empty is working and the method with checking if string is empty and if it's not a number isn't working.

Comment: You should also do this `inputLayoutLastName.setErrorEnabled(false);` outside the for loop above the return true statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minor changes in your solution I think it will work. I haven't tried it in android but I have tried something similar in java(no android) in order to validate the logic.

`private boolean validateLastName() {
    String checkLastName = inputLastName.getText().toString().trim();
    if (checkLastName.isEmpty()) {
        inputLayoutLastName.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_last_name));
        requestFocus(inputLastName);
        return false;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < checkLastName.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(checkLastName.charAt(i))) {
                inputLayoutLastName.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_last_name));
                requestFocus(inputLastName);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    inputLayoutLastName.setErrorEnabled(false);
    return true;
}`

Answer (score 0):

`if (!validateLastName()) {
        return;
    }`

Change this to
`return !validateLastName();`

EDIT:
You actually don't even check for numbers in your if tests, that's why it's not returning false if there are numbers.

`private final CharSequence NUMBERS = "0123456789";
 if (inputName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() &&
     inputName.getText().toString.contains(NUMBERS)) { }`

Comment: I need to check if user have written some numbers and that's why i'm using for loop so i go throw the whole string and check if user have written some number.